# javaScript countdown starts multiple times when links are clicked more than once

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I'm pretty new into JavaScript and would like to implement the following feature:

By clicking a link on the site, a timer with a 15min countdown shall start. That works fine if the link is clicked only once. But if the link (or another one) is clicked again, two (ore more) countdowns are displayed parallelly.
I've tried two different approaches: first, a code that focuses on a `Date()` object and second a version that handles a variable which is successively reduced by one second. Both codes (of course) are based on the `setInterval()` function.

In the first case a log of `stopZeit` shows that each time a link is clicked a new value of `stopZeit` is created. In the second case `console.log(timerLaenge)` shows `30` no matter how often a link is clicked, but there are multiple timers started though.

Here are my two tries:

Version one:

```js
function timer(stopZeit); //stopZeit = time now plus 15min - must be fixed, otherwise it will be actualized everytime the function is called
{
    console.log(stopZeit);

    var countdown = setInterval(function()
    {
        var jetzt = new Date().getTime();       //now
        var differenz = stopZeit - jetzt;       //time difference

        var minuten = Math.floor((differenz % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)); //calculate remaining minutes
        var sekunden = Math.floor((differenz % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);    //calculate remaining seconds

        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = minuten + 'm ' + sekunden + 's ';  //write down the current time difference

        if(differenz < 0)   //check if timer is expired
        {
            clearInterval(countdown);
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = 'Timer abgelaufen!';
        }

    },1000);
}
```

```html
<p id="countdown"></p>

<a href="#" id="neuerLink" onclick="var stopZeit = 0; stopZeit = new Date().getTime()+90000; timer(stopZeit);">Link01</a> <!--declare stopZeit as constant and hand it over to the timer function. -->
<br>
<br>
<a href="##" id="neuerLink" onclick="var stopZeit = 0; stopZeit = new Date().getTime()+90000; timer(stopZeit);">Link02</a> <!--another link-->
```

Version two:

```js
function timer()
{
    timerLaenge = 30;       //length of timer
    console.log(timerLaenge);

    var countdown = setInterval(function()
    {
        timerLaenge = timerLaenge-1;

        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timerLaenge + 's';

        if(timerLaenge < 0)
        {
            clearInterval(countdown);
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = 'Timer abgelaufen!';
        }

    },1000);
}
```

```html
<p id="countdown"></p>

<a href="#" id="neuerLink" onclick="timer();">Link01</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="##" id="neuerLink" onclick="timer();">Link02</a>
```

How can I achieve that the timer is reseted every time a link is clicked again?

Comment: The setInterval function returns an id which you can use to clear the interval. You are trying to clear the interval before it has returned an id. I think you need to store the countdown id globally so you can clear it before you setup a new interval

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome, AlexR_112!

The problem is that `var countdown` happens in a scope of `timer()` and `countdown` gets overwritten on every click. the solution is to store it outside.

I also added a `cancelTimer()` that will stop countdown hope it might helps you in future )

```js
var countdown;
function timer()
{
    if (countdown) {
      return;
    }
    timerLaenge = 30;       //length of timer
    console.log(timerLaenge);

    countdown = setInterval(function()
    {
        timerLaenge = timerLaenge-1;

        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timerLaenge + 's';

        if(timerLaenge < 0)
        {
            clearInterval(countdown);
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = 'Timer abgelaufen!';
        }

    },1000);
}

function cancelTimer()
{
    if (countdown) {
      clearInterval(countdown);
      countdown = null;
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="countdown"></p>

<a href="#" id="neuerLink" onclick="timer();">Link01</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="##" id="neuerLink" onclick="timer();">Link02</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="##" id="neuerLink" onclick="cancelTimer();">Cancel</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To reset the timer everytime user clicks on the link, you can clear the existing timer first before starting the new timer, using [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval).

```js
var countdown; // Bring this variable up one scope 
function timer() {
  timerLaenge = 30; //length of timer
  if(countdown) clearInterval(countdown); // Clear the interval here
  countdown = setInterval(function() {
    timerLaenge = timerLaenge - 1;
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timerLaenge + 's';
    if (timerLaenge < 0) {
      clearInterval(countdown);
      document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = 'Timer abgelaufen!';
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<p id="countdown"></p>

<a href="#" id="neuerLink" onclick="timer();">Link01</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="##" id="neuerLink" onclick="timer();">Link02</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this version works also perfect!